# xerces - Dealing with namespaces in the tag name

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xerces-c

I have an XML based of an XSD that looks something like:

```
<ns1:root xmlns:ns1="ROOT_NAMESPACE">
    <ns1:thing1>abc</ns1:thing>
    <ns1:thing2>def</ns1:thing>
</ns1:root>
```

I'm in C++ and I can successfully read the XML and parse it. But I want to get my elements using the tag name without the namespace, like `thing1` and `thing2`, but at the moment it looks like I need to have it, like `ns1:thing1`. (I'm trying to use the getElementsByTagName method.) How can I make the parser disregard the namespace?

My parser settings are:

```
myParser.setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
myParser.setExternalSchemaLocation(xsdLocation);
myParser.setDoNamespace(true);
myParser.setDoSchema(true);
myParser.setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a new document and rebuild the whole xml-tree without the namespace! It should be easy to go through the tree recursively and build new elements only using the `getLocalName()` method which ignores the prefix.